# How to execute the Entity Framework Model First DDL File on a SqlServer Compact database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

here is something that look easy but drives me crazy since days...

I´m trying to create an application with Entity Framework and Sql Server Compact.
I want to use model first approach.
I created a edmx file for the model and runned the Database Generation wizard which produced an edmx.sqlce file that contains the Table Creation commands.
But where to run this edmx.sqlce file?

I tried to run the file by sending the content to the ExecuteNonQuery Command of the SqlCommand. But it also gives syntax errors - But why should the generated edmx.sqlce file be corrupt??? I think i have to run the file somewhere else.
Can anyone tell me where? (I only have an C# express version).

The content of the edmx.sqlce file is:

```
    -- --------------------------------------------------
    -- Entity Designer DDL Script for SQL Server Compact Edition
    -- --------------------------------------------------
    -- Date Created: 07/27/2011 23:50:28
    -- Generated from EDMX file: C:\Users\Ralf\Programmierung\MySoftware\MySoftware\MySoftwareDatenbank\MySoftwareDataModel.edmx
    -- --------------------------------------------------


    -- --------------------------------------------------
    -- Dropping existing FOREIGN KEY constraints
    -- NOTE: if the constraint does not exist, an ignorable error will be reported.
    -- --------------------------------------------------


    -- --------------------------------------------------
    -- Dropping existing tables
    -- NOTE: if the table does not exist, an ignorable error will be reported.
    -- --------------------------------------------------

        DROP TABLE [DataSourceSet];
    GO

    -- --------------------------------------------------
    -- Creating all tables
    -- --------------------------------------------------

    -- Creating table 'DataSourceSet'
    CREATE TABLE [DataSourceSet] (
        [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    );
    GO

    -- --------------------------------------------------
    -- Creating all PRIMARY KEY constraints
    -- --------------------------------------------------

    -- Creating primary key on [Id] in table 'DataSourceSet'
    ALTER TABLE [DataSourceSet]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_DataSourceSet]
        PRIMARY KEY ([Id] );
    GO

    -- --------------------------------------------------
    -- Creating all FOREIGN KEY constraints
    -- --------------------------------------------------

    -- --------------------------------------------------
    -- Script has ended
    -- --------------------------------------------------
```

My Environment is:
- SqlServerCompact 3.5
- Visual C# 2010 Express

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to run the DDL script manually, it should be done automatically for you the first time you create a DbContext in code that is correctly associated with the desired database connection.  I'm not as familiar with model first as I am with code first, but I understand SQL Server CE 4 is better supported by EF 4.1.

If, for whatever reason, you still want to execute the DDL script manually via ExecuteNonQuery, you'd want to remove all batch terminators ("GO"), as ExecuteNonQuery doesn't support batch queries.

Comment: Thank you I have a solution now.
I had to install Sql Management Studio Express, it can also handle Compact Databases and there i can run the DDL file.

Answer (score 0):

My guess that Model-first approach is a stumbling-stone for SQL CE database. Too much problems with database shema changing and DB architecture.

1. There is one tool for VS2010 <[Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87/)> However its no longer supported.
2. Another usefull extension <[SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1)> for VS 2010-2015 There is build-in sql editor where you can try to run edmx.sqlce file. Although, before running your script file you need to get rid of *GO* and *Alter table* instructions to make it run
3. Or you can use third-party software like *SQL CE Database Editor*